# Authenticate with Azure KeyVault Rest API Without Client Secret?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key

How can I authenticate to azure keyvault via the rest api without passing the client secret? My application is On-Prem. The examples I've found use the client secret to authenticate, which seems to defeat the purpose of KeyVault in the first place if I had to store the client secret locally. I do have the Tenant id, Application ID, and SubjectDistinguishedName of my certificate. Is there a way to authenticate that way with Rest api or some other way that doesn't involve using client secret or some other sensitive piece of data?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some more details. What are you trying to do by authenticating to Key Vault?

Comment: @GauravMantri I didn't think I needed to specify but I want to access the keyvault secret values. I just needed help with the authentication part.

Comment: Thanks. I’m wondering if you’re using Key Vault SDK or using the REST API directly. There are passwordless alternatives if you’re using SDK.

Comment: @GauravMantri I would be using the REST API directly. We tried the SDK route in my organization but our .NET Applications are too old. We are on .NET Framework 4.6.2. That's why I had a suggestion to just use the REST API since that would remove dependency on the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, I suppose you use the client credential flow to get the token, you could use `client_assertion` instead of `client_secret` to get the access token.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<client_id>
&scope=https://vault.azure.net/.default
&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2dxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

See [Access token request with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate) and read about [certificate credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) to learn how to register your certificate and the format of the assertion.

Comment: it looks like I need to keep certificate thumbprint stored in plain text for this to work. How secure is that? Isn't a thumbprint something that should be in a KeyVault instead?

Comment: @Bmoe You can also use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the token, it uses your user credential to auth directly, set your app with [public client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/register-public-azure-ad-client-app#application-registration-overview), then it does not need client secret when getting the token.

Comment: am I reading that article correctly that there would be a login page to authenticate to KeyVault? If so that wouldn't work. We only plan on calling azure on application startup to get the secrets we need (api keys, connection strings, etc.). The end user wouldn't know the wiser.

Comment: @Bmoe There has to be a way for the Key Vault to authenticate the caller.  It's either a client secret (a string), client assertion (a certificate), or a runtime request for username/password.  A certificate with a unexportable private key bound to a user's machine OR a smart card should be a secure scenario for you.  If it's not then you'll need to rethink your security parameters.